# Can Angularjs broadcast event can be executed twice?

Tags: angularjs

I want to execute angularjs broadcast event twice, because I want to change the logic inside angularjs broadcast event. I want to again execute angularjs broadcast event when first finishes. It should wait for one to finish and again execute for second time. How to do that?

Comment: provide some code samples you have done so that it will be easy to answer and check if calling broadcast twice in that situation is appropriate or not.

Comment: you need to wait for the first one to complete and then start the second one?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to wrap the second broadcast in a $timeout which will be emitted first when the callstack is empty. In other words, when the first broadcast and the methods who listen on it are finished.

```
$scope.$broadcast('myEvent', 'Some data');
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.$broadcast('myEvent', 'Some data');
}, 0);
```